# Force required to drive an electric vehicle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

I am looking for the equation to calculate the energy required to move an electric vehicle of simply design based on rolling resistance, weight, wheel radius and air friction.  The idea is to build a digital model with varying values for these inputs and see what rate power is drained from the battery once at a constant speed (around 30mph but may wish this to be variable as well - say 33mph).

Comment: There's more to wind resistance than mere friction.  The vehicle has to push the air out of its way. This causes the air to swirl around and form turbulent vortices in the vehicle's wake. That turbulence has _kinetic energy_ that was robbed from the vehicle.  I don't know any formulas for it, but I think I remember somebody saying that the power required to overcome air resistance is approximately proportional to the _cube_ of the vehicle's speed through the air.

Comment: Thank you Solomon.  Aero-dynamics are being looked at separate in this case.  I was looking for the formula just to turn the wheel.  I have heard that depending on the rolling resistance and CoF by doubling the size of the radius of the wheel you can halve the energy required to turn that wheel (by definition increasing by small amounts would have a proportional effect) .  It is this area we are having a quick look into.

Comment: A perfectly rigid wheel, rolling on a perfectly rigid roadway should use no energy at all. And once again _friction_ plays only a small part in the "rolling resistance" of real car wheels.  The main way that real car wheels lose energy is through _[visicoelasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscoelasticity)_. The rolling rubber tire is continually deformed by the weight of the car, and although it continually returns to its original shape, it does not return all of the energy that was needed to deform it. Some of that energy is converted to heat in the tire material.

Comment: If your roadway is not perfectly flat, then the vehicle's _[shock absorbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashpot)_ also will convert some of the car's kinetic energy to heat every time the car hits a bump or a dip in the road.